# Jquery/Ajax not getting input value from widget

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Have a ajax request sending data to a WordPress action which works fine however I can receive the nonce value perfectly but the email input isn't being sent. I know I'm targeting the right value. It does not want to get the value of the email input. If I hardcode a value into the input it will see it. I need to get the user entered value and send that to the ajax script. The code is also run on document load and is after the form values have been rendered.

Input field looks like this:

```
 <input type="email" name="cjd_email" id="cjd_email" class="cjd-email-input"/>
```

The jquery selector looks like:

```
var cjd_email = $('#cjd_email').val();
```

The ajax call is:

```
$.ajax({
            url: cjdAjax.ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'cjd_subscribe',
                nonce: cjd_nonce,
                email: cjd_email
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                var status  = $(data).find('response_data').text();
                var message = $(data).find('supplemental message').text();

                if(status == 'success') {
                    console.log(message);
                }
                else {
                    console.log(message);

                }
            }
        });
```

Thanks :)

Comment: If you type this in your console what do you see: `console.log($('#cjd_email').length)`

Comment: If the script isn't doin anything check the server error logs

Comment: Have you checked that the `cjd_email` variable contains the correct value before the request is sent?

Comment: When hardcoding the value it sends the email - when I enter in an email address and click submit it doesn't. (like it can't see the entered text)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are having a class on form i.e. cjdajax. Then use serialize method to send data instead of any other.

```
$.ajax({
            url: cjdAjax.ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('.cjdAjax').serialize(),
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {

               //your code
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browser you use, `type=email` might not be supported by jQuery / JavaScript and thus the `valid()` method could return rather strange values. As an alternative, one can use `type=text` with input validation.

Also, you should Review the success function : You attempt to apply the `find()`-method on text rather than a DOM element. The code could be corrected if the server returned a JSON-encoded string, so in JavaScript you could convert the string back into an object.

In PHP one could write `print(json_encode($yourArray, true));` (notice how the `true` flag is required for associative keys), while

```
...
success: function(data){
    var yourObject = JSON.parse(data);
    if (yourObject.responseData === "success")
        console.log(yourObject.message);
},...
```

could replace the respective current JavaScript passage.

Comment: What I find strange is that I have almost the exact same function working in the backend of WordPress perfectly. I am localizing the script and the ajax is being fired - just not reading the single input entered value.

Comment: Could you check if the input is correctly sent and then received by the server? If not, you may `console.log()` the value of the field and, if needed, try out an ordinary `text` input with predefined value to make sure the problem is not with the client.

Comment: Have tried both the above - when a hardcoded value is entered the email is received and sent via admin-ajax.php. console.log() shows an empty value. and when I enter something inside the input nothing gets sent (the nonce does which is fine). It seems to be not reading the entered value on submit.

Comment: I had the very same problem some time ago with Firefox. There, I switched to `<input type="text">`and the solution was working. Now, having tried your code, both IE 11 and Chrome seem to work for me as you want it. If it's neither the browser nor the input type, I can only suggest you trying the most basic setup you can Image, leaving out everything that's not strictly needed in order to concentrate on the important.